# To continue training an existing tensorflow model do I need to restore the session?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I'm trying to work out the best way to integrate with EC2 spot instances that can be started and stopped.

Do I need to store the `tf.session` or can I just do `load_model('myfile.h5')` and continue with `mymodel.fit(....checkpoint=...)` which saves the model every epoch back to `myfile.h5`?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it workng with just `load_model` and then continue with `model.fit(...)`. My model is quite simple, using just Keras `Input`, `LSTM` and `Dense` layers with no variables or anything complex.

Comment: The variables are in there - all the weights are TF variables.

Comment: Ok, cool. So Keras’s save_model effectively saves these TF variables into the h5 file and restores them?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much exactly what it does.